# How to upgrade Python 2.x to latest 2.x version on MacOS

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

I have MacOS Sierra (10.12.6) and had Python 2.7.13 until I did `brew upgrade` and now it is showing 2.7.10 
What is the best proven/safest way to upgrade to latest python 2.x (at this moment 2.7.14)?

Comment: Homebrew’s `python2` is Python 2.7.14. Please show the output of `brew info python2` as well as `which python2` and `python2 --version` so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

It is curious Python 2.7.13 in Sierra.  I thought that Apple has only included Python 2.7.10 for since at least as far back as El Capitan and still on High Sierra.  I am on High Sierra and python -v is still 2.7.10 for example. I skipped Sierra so I don't know from personal experience on that one.

You are probably typing python -V in a terminal right? Are you sure which version of python is being found first in the path?  Brew can't overwrite Sierra's Python (SIP would protect it from anything trying to change the included Python version) and installs it in usr/local.  Brew is the best way I know of for installing Python and you have multiple versions of Python installed with Brew.  Take a look in your /usr/local/bin folder.  `ls /usr/local/bin/python*` at the terminal will do it.  You probably will have a python2 and maybe a python3 in there, maybe more than one.  Brew puts a number after Python for the major version to distinguish it from the system Python.  Assuming everything went smooth with Brew then at the terminal you should be able to type python2 -V and or python3 -V depending on which version of python you installed with brew.  A reasonably good tutorial for setting up Python on a mac is here http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/osx/

Answer (score 0):

If you have brew installed and Python 2.x.x run...

```
brew upgrade python@2
```

If you have brew installed and no Python 2.x.x run...

```
brew install python@2
```